# Java Threads: How to find the right place in code to create a new thread for a program that allows multiple clients to connect to the server

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm creating two program files (one client one server). The client code has to be able to create multiple clients to connect to the server (there is only one server, there can be a multiple and/or infinite number of clients). One new thread has to be created for each client that connects to the server. The way to create a client will be opening a new command prompt / mac terminal window and run the client file. Once a client is connected, it can send messages to the server. It will also receive from the server all messages sent from the other connected clients.

We will focus on the client code for now. (no server code yet)

In the following code there are two places where I created new threads, I am not sure which place it should be located because there are no errors when I run the program in eclipse.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.*;
public class ChatClient
{
    private static Socket Socket;
    static int numberOfClients = 0;
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {


          //If I wanted to create multiple clients, would this code go here? OR should the new thread creation be outside the while(true) loop?
          while (true)
          {
              try 
              {
                  String host = "localhost";
                  InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
                  numberOfClients += 1;
                  Thread ChatClient1 = new Thread ()
                  {
                      public void run()
                      {   
                          ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
                          Socket socket = null;
                          try 
                          {
                              int numberofmessages = 0;
                              String[] messagessentbyotherclients = null;
                              System.out.println("Try block begins..");
                              System.out.println("Chat client is running");
                              String port_number1= args[0];
                              System.out.println("Port number is: " + port_number1);
                              int port = Integer.valueOf(port_number1);
                              System.out.println("Listening for connections..");
                              System.out.println( "Listening on port: " + port_number1 );
                              serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
                              for(int i = 0; i < numberOfClients; i++)
                              {
                                  System.out.println(messagessentbyotherclients);
                              }
                          }
                          catch (IOException e)
                          {
                              e.printStackTrace();
                          }
                      }
                  };
                  ChatClient1.start();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("I/O error: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

}
My question is: Should the thread be created right underneath the main function or inside the while(true) loop? (the while true loop will eventually be exited by control D in standard input)

Comment: perhaps creating two separate programs, one for the client and one for the server is what you want to do instead putting all the logic of server and client into a single program.

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz yeah I should delete the serversocket code, sorry it is a bit misleading but I would like this to just be the client file but I am scared to get rid of anything due to the fact that I will end up with more errors but I am willing to try eventually

Comment: well from your example it looks like you have two things going on that i can see, first you never call start() on your ChatClient1 thread and second your value for numberofclients is always 0.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Why would you multi-thread a clientif you state that "The way to create a client will be opening a new command prompt / mac terminal window and run the client file"? Also, please honor the java convention of starting variable names with a lowercase letter and writing long variable names in camelCases. You can find a comprehensive guide of naming conventions [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). Furhtermore, I see nothing eclipse-related in your question.

Comment: Why does your client have a `ServerSocket`? You'll only be confusing yourself if you don't separate them right from the start. Also, you'll be able to find plenty of examples if you do it the standard way.

Comment: Yeeeeh, your code is quite confusing. And also you state 'no server code yet', but you use a ServerSocket. I'd recommend to start with a hello-world approach: Write a type Server, write a type Client and send a message in both directions and start from there ...

Comment: @Turing85 You might be correct that I don't need to create multiple threads, but only one. Although if that is the case then my question is: if each client connects to the server on the same port, how do you distinguish one client from the other one or should they all have different ports?


-Kayaman Sorry I have now edited the code to get rid of the server code hopefully (correct me if I missed something I'll go and delete it soon).


-slowy Sorry, I hopefully fixed it now (correct me if i'm wrong)

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz sorry I think i fixed the code to not include the server now, (correct me if i missed something)

Comment: sorry everyone try refreshing the page (i made multiple corrections/removal of server code)

Comment: @Eric what do you mean by "distinguish"? Where or why would you need to distinguish? Connections are distinguished by the corresponding `Socket`s. The client opens a connection by creating a `Socket` to the server. The `ServerSocket.accept()` returns a new `Socket`, representing the specific (accepted) connection. Do not use separate ports because you have no possibility to "tell" a new client on which port your server is now listening for a new connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is so far from a working solution, that I don't think commenting on it is helpful to you at this point. As people in comments have already explained you should have 2 executables for client and server. What you do right now is to spawn server threads in the inner loops without any chance of creating more than one client that connects to the same server.

The usual way to write a multi-threaded client/server app using one thread per client is to write a server-executable, which opens a `ServerSocket`, which does `accept` and spawns a new `Thread` to handle the client-socket in a loop.

Then you write a client-executable, which uses a `Socket` to `connect` to the server (on the port used to spawn the server), and talks to the server.

Communication can be done using the input/output streams you get from the sockets at both ends of the connection.

This looks a lot like homework, so I won't provide working code, but you can try to follow these steps:

- Make two classes with a main-method each
- In one class create a `Socket`, which calls `connect` to the server. Try to send the simplest possible message from the client, such as a line containing "hello world". `PrintWriter` can e.g. be used to wrap the `OutputStream` of the socket in a more convenient interface.
- In the other class create a `ServerSocket` and call `accept` in a loop, handing the returned `Socket`s to new `Thread`s, which loop over the input from the client until a terminating signal is received from the client or the connection is closed (IOException). You can start with reading line by line by wrapping the `InputStream` in a `BufferedReader` and just printing what the client sends.
- Ensure communication works both ways by sending/receiving responses (Server writes response to `OutputStream` of the socket associated with the client, client reads `InputStream` of it's socket)
- Implement your application's protocol over the connection

When you are done, you first start the server, then run as many clients against it as you want. The server needs to be started first, because the `connect` call will internally open a connection, which can only be completed, if a server is listening on the port the client connects to. If the threading is complicated at all for you, try writing a server that just accepts a connection, then reads a line from it, and closes it before adding the threaded logic. From your code it seems to me like you don't seem to fully understand how a client/server-connection works. Right now you can't even have one client, because - all other issues aside - you call neither `accept` nor `connect`.